# how to split string by double quoted word by avoiding escaped quote

Tags: javascript, regex

How to split the below string

```
var test = 'sample "test""test2"   "test3\\"" sample2"last';
```

into an array `['sample','"test"','"test2"','"test3\\""','sample2"last']`  using javascript regx ?

Some sample input and expected output are added below.

```
sample1 : ' test1 "test2" test3 "test four\\"" test" d'
output [' test1','"test2"','test3','"test four\\""','test" d']

sample2 : ' test1 test2'
output [' test1 test2']

sample3 : ' test1 "sub test2'
output [' test1 "sub test2']

sample4 : ' test1 "sub test2"'
output [' test1 ','"sub test2"']

sample5 : ' "test1" "sub test2" here'
output ['"test1"','"sub test2"', 'here']
```

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: str = str.replace(/"\s+"|""/g, '","');
var res = str.split(",");
tried this but doesn't support escaped and wanted to do both by regx.

Comment: @Teemu it means zero or more than zero 'space'

Comment: If you want to preserve the masking character `\\` in your string you will need to put it there twice, otherwise it will be swallowed at the time of the string generation. I can't even get to make it appear double in this comment :D !

Comment: According to your splitting rules the last word "sample2" should not appear in your results array as it is not enclosed in quotation marks.

Comment: Do you realize how much havoc you are causing by continually changing the question? I doubt that any of the answers are correct now.

Comment: :D yes, who can follow all of these changes ?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work for you for splitting:

```
/\s*"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"\s*|.+?(?="[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|$)/g
```

**Code:**

```js
var input = [` test1 "test2" test3 "test four\\"" test" d`, ` test1 test2`, ` test1 "sub test2`, `' test1 "sub test2"`, ` "test1" "sub test2" here`];

const re = /\s*"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"\s*|.+?(?="[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|$)/g;

input.forEach(el => {
  console.log('<<', el, '>>');
  var arr = el.match(re);
  arr.forEach(i => console.log(i));
});
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`: Match a quoted string ignoring escaped quotes
- `|`: OR
- `.+?(?="[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|$)`: Match 1+ any characters that must be followed by a quoted string or end of line.

Answer (score 2):

You can split the string by non alphanumeric characters, then remove any element with 0 length.

```js
var test = 'sample "test""test2"   "test3\"" sample2"';

var array = test.split(/\W/g).filter(e => e.length>0);

console.log(array);
```

Comment: double quotes should not be escaped ..check the updated question

Comment: This is not giving expected results as you can see that OP wants to capture quotes also in output.

Answer (score 0):

A little convoluted, but it does the job:

- first replace the masked quotation marks with a marker string `x`
- then: match any `"`-enclosed string parts using the `RegExp.exec()` method repeatedly
- grab the first element of each result, remove the quotation marks and replace the marker string with the original quotation mark and
- push it into the results array

```js
var test = 'sample "test""test2"   "test3\\"" sample2"';
var x='@#@',xr= RegExp(x,'g');
var rx=/"[^"]+"/g; // matches "-enclosed strings
var a,arr=[];
while (a=rx.exec(test.replace(/\\"/g,x)))
arr.push(a[0].replace(/"/g,'').replace(xr,'"'));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use negative lookbehind, you can use this pattern:

```
test.split(/(?<!\\)"/).map(i => i.trim()).filter(i => i != '')
```

Note, that negative lookbehind is recent addition to JS engines. It can be used with V8, which is used for example in Chrome.

If you are not able to use negative lookbehind, then use workaround: reverse the string, use negative lookahead, then reverse again:

```
test
  .split('')
  .reverse()
  .join('')
  .split(/"(?!\\)/)
  .map(i => i.trim())
  .filter(i => i != '')
  .map(i => i.split('').reverse().join(''))
  .reverse()
```

Patterns used:

- `"(?!\\)` - negative lookahead: match `"` which is not followed by `\`
- `(?<!\\)"` - negative lookbehind: match `"` which is not preceeded by `\`

Answer (score 0):

A pure regexp solution : `/ +|(?<!\\")(?<=")(?=")/`

This matches either space(s), or empty strings that are

- preceded by `"` but not `\"`
- followed by `"`

```js
var test = 'sample "test""test2"   "test3\\"" sample2"last';
console.log(test.split(/ +|(?<!\\")(?<=")(?=")/));
```

Comment: It's correct.But it fails when extra space comes like 'sample2"  last'.As like my title says (split when double quote comes) it shouldn't split for normal string like 'sample last' ..it's seperating here..can you help for that case..

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/dqtokenizer

```
const dqtokenizer = require('dqtokenizer');

const testTokenize = (str, options) => {
    const tokens = dqtokenizer.tokenize(str, options);
    console.log();
    console.log(`str: ${str}`);
    console.log(`tokens:`);
    tokens.forEach((token, index) => console.log(`\t${index}: ${token}`));
}

const sample1 = ' test1 "test2" test3 "test four\\"" test" d';
// output [' test1','"test2"','test3','"test four\\""','test" d']
testTokenize(sample1);

const sample2 = ' test1 test2'
// output [' test1 test2']
testTokenize(sample2);

const sample3 = ' test1 "sub test2'
// output [' test1 "sub test2']
testTokenize(sample3);

const sample4 = ' test1 "sub test2"'
// output [' test1 ','"sub test2"']
testTokenize(sample4);

const sample5 = ' "test1" "sub test2" here'
// output ['"test1"','"sub test2"', 'here']
testTokenize(sample5);
```

Output:

```
str:  test1 "test2" test3 "test four\"" test" d
tokens:
        0: test1
        1: "test2"
        2: test3
        3: "test four\""
        4: test
        5: " d

str:  test1 test2
tokens:
        0: test1
        1: test2

str:  test1 "sub test2
tokens:
        0: test1
        1: "sub test2

str:  test1 "sub test2"
tokens:
        0: test1
        1: "sub test2"

str:  "test1" "sub test2" here
tokens:
        0: "test1"
        1: "sub test2"
        2: here
```